# returns the exact returned value if wget fails

Tags: bash, wget

I'd love to return the exact value if `wget` command fails in efficient way without changing it.

Can `exit #?` output the returned value from `wget`?

Ex.

```
# If it succeeds, then wget returns zero instead of non zero
## 0    No problems occurred.
## 1    Generic error code.
## 2    Parse error—for instance, when parsing command-line options, the ‘.wgetrc’ or ‘.netrc’...
## 3    File I/O error.
## 4    Network failure.
## 5    SSL verification failure.
## 6    Username/password authentication failure.
## 7    Protocol errors.
## 8    Server issued an error response.
wget https://www.google.co.jp/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png -o test.img
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
    # exit 16 # failed ends1 <== This doesn't tell anything
    exit #?
fi
```

Comment: In the first line of your example you say "# if the image fetching is succeeded (non zero)". That comment is misleading. If it succeeds, then wget returns zero instead of non zero.

Comment: yeah i'll fix it

Comment: One alternative, since you're using Bash, is to use `set -e` - it's only documented to exit with a non-zero status, but it seems (in version 4.4, at least) to propagate the status of the failing command, even if further commands are run via the `EXIT` trap.  For example, `( trap 'echo $?' EXIT; set -e; ( exit 3 ) ; echo true ) ; echo $?` emits `3` from both `echo` commands.  Hold on, that's worth writing as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
wget https://www.google.co.jp/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png -o test.img
# grab wget's exit code
exit_code=$?
# if exit code is not 0 (failed), then return it
test $exit_code -eq 0 || exit $exit_code
```

Answer (score 1):

The `-e` option of Bash may do what you want:

> Exit  immediately  if  a *pipeline* (which may consist of a single *simple command*), a *list*, or a *compound command* (see **SHELL GRAMMAR**), exits with a non-zero status.

It's also important to know that

> Bash's exit status  is the  exit  status  of  the last command executed in the script.

My experiments with Bash 4.4 suggest that the exit status of the failing command is returned, even if a trap handler is invoked:

```
$ ( trap 'echo $?' ERR; set -e; ( exit 3 ) ; echo true ) ; echo $?
3
3
```

So you can write:

```
#!/bin/bash

url=https://www.google.co.jp/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png

set -e
wget -o test.img "$url"
set +e    # if you no longer want exit on fail
```

For just one command in your script, you might prefer an explicit test and exit like this:

```
wget -o test.img "$url"  || exit $?
```

Further, `exit` with no argument is the same as `exit $?`, so that can be simplified to just

```
wget -o test.img "$url"  || exit
```

Comment: For the described problem (not the proposed solution by the author) this should be accepted.